# SqlServer Powershell Module - Can Restore-SqlDatabase -AutoRelocate rename files?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

- Powershell Version: 5.1.19041.1320
- SqlServer Module Version:
- 21.1.18256 SSMS Version: 15.0.18390.0

I am attempting to compose some Powershell scripts which automate some backup and restore activities my org requires. Because reasons, a backup and restore will sometimes take place on the same SQL Server instance, in effect cloning one database under a new name.

SSMS can handle this case trivially in their UI, just by specifying the new database name on the wizard. Doing so generates a script like so:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [NewDatabaseName] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Folder\BackupFileName.bak' WITH  FILE = 40,  MOVE N'Database_Data' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ServerInstance\MSSQL\DATA\NewDatabaseName.mdf',  MOVE N'Database_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ServerInstance\MSSQL\DATA\NewDatabaseName.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
```

Simple and obvious enough. Trying to accomplish this same thing with the SqlServer module, using the -AutoRelocate and -Script flags, yields the following:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [NewDatabaseName] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Folder\BackupFileName.bak' WITH  MOVE N'Database_Data' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ServerInstance\MSSQL\DATA\OldDatabaseName.mdf',  MOVE N'Database_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ServerInstance\MSSQL\DATA\OldDatabaseName.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

In particular, it does *not* automatically attempt to rename the .mdf and .ldf files the way that SSMS does, preserving the backed up database name. This poses a potential future headache when backing up across servers, and will fail outright when done on the same server due to the conflict. Omitting the -AutoRelocate flags just removes the moves altogether, functionally resulting in the same thing.

There's a number of things I can do here. I can obviously just execute the correct scripts directly, or I can prep the RelocateFile argument for Restore-SqlDatabase. What I want to understand is if I'm missing something obvious that will permit me to skip having to do those things so the tool can handle this automatically, as SSMS might.

Thank you. :)

Comment: `-AutoRelocate` only changes the folder path to the SQL Server instance's default data directory. This is useful for backup/restore operations between different SQL Server instances on the same host. If you want to rename the data/log files you'll need to use the `-Relocate` switch with an array of SMO.RelocateFile parameters.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning that's exactly what I'm currently trying to achieve, but AFAIK this would require me to know the exact names of data and log files sitting in the backup. Could you please give some hints on how to do this? A more detailed answer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The parameters have been renamed to `-AutoRelocateFile` and `-RelocateFile` since I wrote my comment, but you could start by [reading the friendly documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/restore-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps) which even includes an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually relocate the data and log files using the -RelocateFile parameter of the Restore-SqlDatabase command.
There is example code available to do this when your database has just one data file and one log file.

I have a database that has four datafiles and one log file spread across 5 different disks.

I will assume your script is already running in the SQLSERVER drive and you have all the necessary access rights.

```
$Backup = "C:\Folder\BackupFileName.bak"
$NewDatabaseName = "MySandboxDatabase"
$sqlFileName = $NewDatabaseName
$sqlFileList = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'$Backup' WITH NOUNLOAD"

$dataLogicals = ($sqlFileList | Where-Object -Property Type -eq "D")
$logLogical   = ($sqlFileList | Where-Object -Property Type -eq "L")

$RelocateObjects = @()
$i = 1

$dataLogicals | %{
    $dataLogical = $_

    $filename = $dataLogical.PhysicalName
    $fileobj  = Get-ChildItem $filename
    $folder   = $fileobj.DirectoryName
    $ext      = $fileobj.Extension  

    $newDataFile =  Join-Path -Path $folder -ChildPath "$($sqlFileName)_data$($i).$($ext)"
    $i++
    Write-Host "Relocating $filename to $newDataFile"
    $RelocateData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile($dataLogical.LogicalName, $newDataFile )
    $RelocateObjects += $RelocateData
}

# Do the same with $logLogical, adding the $RelocateData object to the $RelocateObjects array.
# I do this:
$RelocateLog  = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile($logLogical.LogicalName,  $ldfFile )
$RelocateObjects += $RelocateLog

# Now you can perform the restore, relocating each of the files.

Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $yourSqlServer -Database $NewDatabaseName -BackupFile "$Backup" -RelocateFile $RelocateObjects -ErrorAction Stop
```